# PyQtGraph in Anaconda produces frozen/crashed Python window

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to draw a simple plot using PyQtGraph in Anaconda (Windows 7 SP1 Home Premium, on a brand new Windows install that only has Anaconda and Arduino IDE installed) as a test to check PyQtGraph's abilities:

```
#Very simple test to see if Python crashes with PyQtGraph in Anaconda
import pyqtgraph as pg
x = [1, 2, 3] 
y = [5, 6, 7] 
pg.plot(x, y)
```

When I try to run it, I get "Python (Not Responding)".

I've tried Running it in a Python 3.5 environment using PyQt4 and PyQt5, and I've tried the same in a Python 2.7 environment. I've tried in Jupyter, PyQt Console and Spyder and always get the same frozen window.

Any ideas on how this could be remedied?

Comment: If you want interactive plotting then first type `%gui qt` in IPython (i.e. Jupyter or PyQt Console). This will enable [GUI event loop integration](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/interactive/magics.html#magic-gui). In the past PyQT could do this by itself but I don't know if it still can, so I would just use IPython for this.

Comment: @titusjan: thanks, this solved about 2 hours of frustration for me.